# Overhead in returning from a method

Tags: c#, sql-server, networking, latency

I have a method A() that processes some queries. This method, from opening bracket to just before its return statement, times at +/-70ms. A good 50% of which comes from opening the connection, about 20% comes from the actual queries, 5-10% is used by some memory access, the rest is (probably) used for disposing the connection, commands and reader.

Although this big chunk of time used for handling the connection is annoying enough, what bothers me more is that when I call A() from method B():

```
B()
{
    var timer = Stopwatch.Startnew()
    A(); 
    timer.Stop(); // elapsed: +/- 250ms
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

Another 180ms of lag gets added and I can't seem to figure out why. I already tried having A return null, which changes nothing.

The only disk I/O and networking happens in A. I thought the transfer from disk and network to local memory should've happened in A, and therefore a call to A from B should not be influenced by this, but apparently this is not the case? Is this network latency I'm experiencing here? If so, then why does this also happen when I just let B return null?

I have no other explanation at the moment...

- Everything resides in the same assembly,
- Measuring without a debugger attached changes nothing,
- Returning 'null' immediately show 0 ms, returning null instead of the normal return value changes nothing (but enforces the idea this is somehow related to latency).

A is roughly implemented as follows, like any simple method accessing a database. It's contrived, but shows the basic idea and flow:

```
A()
{   
    var totalTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var stuff = new Stuffholder();

    using(connection)
    {
         using(command)
         {
              using(reader) 
              { 
                  // fill 'stuff' 
              }
         } 
    }

    totalTimer.Stop(); // elapsed: +/- 70ms
    return stuff;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: After the timer in B stopped (see edit).

Comment: ok thanks, i thought that might be it but it isnt

Comment: Is `A()` living in different assembly than `B()`?

Comment: are you reading EllapsedTicks or ElapsedMilliseconds?

Comment: Try measuring without debugger attached.

Comment: No, everything is in the same assembly. Perhaps it's worth noting A is a static method.

Comment: @Nikita Brizhak, without the debugger attached changes nothing.

Comment: Does `A`'s static class have a constructor?

Comment: @Weyland Yutani, ElapsedMilliseconds

Comment: what if A is just an empty method (probably you have already tried this)

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović The class itself is not static, and I tried & timed this by calling A from both a static context as from the (non static) constructor

Comment: @WeylandYutani If I immediately return null, the elapsed time is 0 milliseconds, when I replace the 'normal' return value with null nothing changes. This leads me to think it indeed is some latency issue

Comment: no idea you might have to post the code for A()

Comment: Are the figures you are posting averages over a few thousand repeated attempts in the same test, or one off figures?

Comment: Doh, not so smart of me... Average over a 1000 calls, minus the first, shows much better numbers (18ms total). But everytime I restart the first call is slow. I actually knew I should've tried this, why didn't I? Cheers!

Comment: That is the just in time compiler: the first time the method is called it gets compiled.

Comment: Yeah, figured. Thanks though.. Sometimes you're just staring at something *.*. If you turn it into an answer, I can accept it :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overhead that you are seeing is due to just-in-time compilation. The first time method `B()` is called method `A()` has not been natively compiled (it is partially compiled in the dll as IL), so you see a slight lag while the compiler compiles `A()` into machine code.

When profiling a method call it is important to call the method a large number of times and take the average time (discarding the first call if you like, although over enough calls the compilation overhead should become insignificant).

Comment: Or try ngen-ing the whole thing before benchmarking - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you have database access in A() you might be suffering from network name resolution issues, so your first call take a while longer to execute.